# How can i transfer my Tezos coins

Tags: tezos-client

hope all is well with you. I will appreciate it if you can help me and explain to me what I should do .3 years ago during 2017 I bought Tezos coins from   https://tezos.com/.The company sent me a confirmation email for the coins I bought and also they sent me a public keyhash throw pdf file. I have an account on a trading platform, and I would like to transfer my Tezos coin to my account on the trading platform. I generate from the trading platform Tezos address so I can transfer the Tezos coin I bought to my account in the trading platform.

If you can please help me by explaining to me the steps I need to take to send my Tezos coin to my account in the Traken platform. Thanks in advance Best regards

Comment: Tezos Stack Exchange is for well defined technical questions. This question is being closed as it should be asked on the Tezos riot, telegram, reddit channels.

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate your account, see https://tezos.com/get-started#activate for the details.

> The company sent me [..]

Tezos is a blockchain not a company, you probably mean the Tezos Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you dear Raphael for your answer and help.i appreciate your help
I did as you wrote, I activate my account and i received that my KYC/AML Process Complete and I got Public Key Hash #1 and got Activation Code #1 and when I tired Activate my Recommended Allocation and wrote the 2 codes I got then got this message :

We were unable to activate a recommended allocation corresponding to the information that was entered. Please make sure that a public key hash from the fundraiser and the associated activation code obtained after completing the Foundation’s KYC/AML process here are entered correctly. If a balance for a given public key hash from the fundraiser appears on a Tezos block explorer, then the activation process has already been completed and no further action is needed.

then I open an account in GitHUB , what else I need to do and where I can find the Tezos coin I bought?

Thanks in advance for your help